# Meaning of '///' after 'file:' protocol (URL)

Tags: url, file-uri

Why does `file:` protocol has 3 (back)slashes in this URL?

```
file:///C:/Users
```

(`C:/Users` is the path name of this URL.)

How does an URL parser handle it?

---

I thought the last slash of these 3 slashes could mean 'path', I put a host name before declaring it, like

```
file://domainname.extension/C:/Users
```

but JavaScript's URL parser ignores this domain name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To make things easier to understand, here `file://` is the protocol and `/` is the root directory.

And later occurring terms are subdirectory, as in `http://google.com`: here `http://` is the protocol and `google.com` is the root directory.

This is a URI scheme, typically used to retrieve files from within one's own computer.

For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme

Comment: Yes, I thought on that, but JavaScript's URL parser ignores the root directory. Do you think there are rules for file: protocol?

Comment: this is just meant to be used by browsers to browse files only on the same system... 
do you ever used it at any other place.. other than browser... where it showed a successful result..

Comment: I think I got it, the Wiki examples did the same action as in the JS's URL parser. Replying, if I used these URLs in elsewhere, this may have been a long time ago