# Is it possible to use env variables into a local file URI protocol?

Tags: url, browser, bookmarks, file-uri

Knowing that we have the file URI protocol to reference local files in a browser bookmark as this question ( [Meaning of '///' after 'file:' protocol (URL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070699/meaning-of-after-file-protocol-url) ) already explains...

What if I wnat to use an environment variable into this path? Is it possible?

For example, I would like to use windows 'USERPROFILE' like that:

file:///%USERPROFILE%/someFolder/someFile.html

Instead of having the fixed:

file:///C:/Users/miwindowsusername/someFolder/someFile.html

Comment: Basically you could use a variable from an .env file to build a path. But you need to process that on the server-side before the browser can render the path in your html code (for example in PHP). Can't think of a way to do this in plain html (via javascript calling a PHP file maybe but then you could do it on the server-side directly). Naming PHP as an example only, there are more